# AngularJS child scope bindings: behavior I can't explain

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm developing with angularJS since a while now.
For a workshop I will give, I built a very simple fiddle to explain the different angular bindings: '@', '&', '='.

So far so good, here is the fiddle, nothing crazy there: http://jsfiddle.net/Djul/gpxgount/5/

The javascript code:

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.parentAt = "At";
    $scope.parentAmpersand = "Apersand";
    $scope.parentEqual = "Equal";

    $scope.updateParentVariables = function(){
        $scope.parentAt= 'parentAt';
        $scope.parentAmpersand= 'parentdAmpersan';
        $scope.parentEqual = 'parentdEqual';
    };

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.parentAt = 'At';
        $scope.parentAmpersand = 'Ampersand';
        $scope.parentEqual = 'Equal';
    };
}

angular.module('myTestApp', []);

angular.module('myTestApp').directive('testBindings', function(){
    return{
        template: '<p>Child scope values:</p><p>{{testAt}}</p><p>{{testAmpersand}}</p><p>{{testEqual}}</p><button ng-click="updateChildVariables()">Update Variables in child scope</button>',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            testAt: '@',
            testAmpersand: '&',
            testEqual: '='
        },
        link: function(scope){
            scope.updateChildVariables = function(){
                scope.testAt = 'childAt';
                scope.testAmpersand= 'childAmpersand';
                scope.testEqual = 'childEqual';
            }
        }
    };
})
.directive('controllerScopeUpdate', function(){
    return{
        template:'<button ng-click="updateParentVariables()">Update variables in parent scope</button><p>Controller Values:</p><p>{{parentAt}}</p><p>{{parentAmpersand}}</p><p>{{parentEqual}}</p><button ng-click="reset()">reset to original values</button>',
        restrict: 'E'
    }
});
```

If you try to do:
 1. update parent variables
 2. update child variables
 3. update parent variables again
 4. !! the value of the @ parameter is not changed in the child scope!

But even more weird, if you do "reset" it will work again until the second click on "update parent variables"...

I'm I missing something?
Why is reset working all the time whereas "update parent variable" is only working only once between each click on reset?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry the link to the good fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/Djul/gpxgount/5/

Comment: `@` is simply an attribute value as a string. It is not bound to the parent scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit - I was somewhat puzzled by this, but only because the usage you are describing is somewhat unusual, with unusually-encountered side effects

The reason a second assignment from the parent doesn't work is because the interpolated value for `{{parentAt}}` hasn't changed, and so the `"@"` binding is not updating the inner scope's value. Or, more accurately, [`$watch(interpolateFn, )`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/compile.js#L2402) does not fire since the value returned by `interpolateFn` has not changed.

And so when you assign the value `"parentAt"` to it (**again!**) the binding's last value is still "parentAt", and so it does not detect a change and doesn't update `scope.testAt`.

As a simple test, change the value of `$scope.parentAt` each time the `updateParentVariables` is called - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/smwt8xts/) - and you will see that the value always updates.

**Slightly off-topic:**

Your `scope.testAmpersand` treatment is also "broken". For one, to display the value, you'd need to invoke it as a function:

```
{{testAmpersand()}}
```

But, when you assign a string value to it - `testAmpersand = "childAmpersand"`, you are "breaking" its connection to the `"&"`-bound expression.

Comment: many thanks! This little "unexpected" behavior is quite dangerous actually! It's nice to have it in mind and understood, indeed in the parent the value is not changed anymore and remains parentAt and don't get propagated.

Regarding the ampersand example it is intended like that do show it does not work with variable, in the fiddle you have the function commented and ready to illustrate it working.

Comment: @Piou, why is it dangerous? One rarely, if ever, needs to assign a value to the otherwise one-way bound scope variable.

Comment: You're right, I was hoping there was a check the value were still correlated,but that makes sens it's not. This would only be useful in the case you want the value to live on its own in th child scope but the parent value acts as master switch. I meant it's "Dangerous" do not have it scoped, so thanks for that